# How can I remove extra % and digit from url?

Tags: php, mysql, url

I Want to get id in next page url. But there are many `%` and digit with id. example: my id should 13 after url. but it becoming
http://localhost/daudkandi/photo_upload.php?id=%27%20.%2013%20.%20%27

How can I remove % and extra digit?

Here is my total code

```
<?php @session_start(); ?>
<?php include "db.php";

$union=$_POST["union"];
$mouja=$_POST["mouja"];
$khatian=$_POST["khatian"];
$extra=$_POST["extra"];
$creator=$_SESSION["email"];
$c_date=(time());
$table="form";




mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table(`id`, `union`, `mouja`, `khatian`, `extra`, `creator`, `c_date`) 
            VALUES(NULL,'$union','$mouja','$khatian','$extra', '$creator', '$c_date')") or die(mysql_error());

                        $id = mysql_insert_id();
                        $sql="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id='$id' AND creator='$creator'";                      
                        $result=mysql_query($sql);
                        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    header("Location: photo_upload.php?id=' . $row[0] . '");

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong string concatenation. Your final string looks like `Location: photo_upload.php?id=' . 13 . '`. Use one of these codes to concatenate strings:

```
header("Location: photo_upload.php?id=".$row[0]);
header("Location: photo_upload.php?id={$row[0]}");
header('Location: photo_upload.php?id='.$row[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The

```
header("Location: photo_upload.php?id=' . $row[0] . '");
```

has extra spaces and dots around $row[0] that are being urlencoded to

```
%27%20.%2013%20.%20%27
```

Trim the extra dots and spaces to get photo_upload.php?id=13

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by :

```
header("Location: photo_upload.php?id=".$row[0]);
```

And where you get your id,, just use `urldecode($_GET['id']);`  to remove it.